# Systemd removes (host) routes on suspend

Tags: networking, routing, systemd

System removes custom routes after suspend and resume.

When I add a route

```
ip route add 1.2.3.4 via 5.6.7.8
```

It is removed after suspend and resume. This is annyoing, because it e.g. removes host routes from openvpn, which renders the vpn connection unusable afterwards.

I did confirm the bug in debian and ubuntu and in debian I confirmed that it does not happen with sysvinit.

What do I need to configure, such that systemd does not touch the routing table at all?
I have some scripts which do quite a bit of network configuration and would like that no other part of the system changes the configuration.

Comment: If you've confirmed that it's a _bug_, why even assume it can be configured away? Most bugs need bugfixes.

Comment: Before confrming a bug, I need to know if it isn't just a configuration issue. I would not believe, that nobody noticed that systemd in a default configuration removes routes, so it probably is no bug, but something you can configure. I at least hope so.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonders of systemd. As far as I know, you cannot have systemd ignore the routing. As far as I know, it does so explicitly (ie feature, not bug). However, you can run scripts at sleep/resume time. See `man systemd-suspend.service` foe details.

Basically, you put a script in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`, that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "post" ] ; then
    ip route add 1.2.3.4 via 5.6.7.8
    # or call the script that already creates the routing table
fi
```

Note: the directory might be `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` (without `/usr`)

Comment: You assume that all systemd features live in a single program. The service manager doesn't touch networking; the _systemd-networkd_ network manager does – that is, if OP chose to enable and use it.

Comment: No, I was refering to systemd as the whole suite, not as the single instance of the daemon.

Comment: It works as workaround, but I need to put a ``sleep`` before the vpn restart command. ``sleep 3`` works for me, but probably it depends on the system and how slow or fast systemd reconfigures network related stuff after resume.